# Realize event listener and life cycle with "functional component"

Tags: reactjs

I am Japanese.
Therefore, please understand that English may be strange.

I'm currently making a typing game.
The game is already complete by using class components.

But when I replace class component with functional component, it doesn’t work.
Is there a way for event listeners to work?

- Class Component

```js
import React from "react";

class Game extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.maxSubject = 10;
    this.state = {
      subject: "",
      inputContent: "",
      correctCount: 0,
      incorrectCount: 0,
      elapsedTime_ms: 0,
    };
  }

  keyList = [
  "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", "-", "^", "\\", 
  "@", "[",
  ";", ":", "]",
  ",", ".", "/",
  
  "!", "\"", "#", "$", "%", "&", "'", "(", ")", "=", "~", "|",
  "`", "{",
  "+", "*", "}",
  "<", ">", "?", "_"
  ];

  generateSubject() {
    const rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.keyList.length);
    const subject = this.keyList[rnd];
    this.setState({subject: subject});
  }

  readInputKey = (e) => {
    let pressedKey = e.key
    this.setState({inputContent: pressedKey})
    this.checkCorrectness();
  }

  checkCorrectness() {
    if(this.state.inputContent === this.state.subject) {
      this.handleCorrect();
    } else {
      this.handleIncorrect();
    }
  }

  handleCorrect() {
    this.setState({
      correctCount: this.state.correctCount + 1,
      inputContent: ""
    });
    if(this.state.correctCount >= this.maxSubject) {
      this.handleSubejctFinish();
    } else {
      this.generateSubject();
    }
  }

  handleIncorrect() {
    this.setState({
      incorrectCount: this.state.incorrectCount + 1,
    });
  }

  handleSubejctFinish() {
    this.setState({elapsedTime_ms: Date.now() - this.state.elapsedTime_ms})
    this.props.sendResult(this.state.correctCount, this.state.incorrectCount, this.state.elapsedTime_ms);
    this.props.handleScreen("result");
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({elapsedTime_ms: Date.now()})
    this.generateSubject();
    window.addEventListener("keypress", this.readInputKey)
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener("keypress", this.readInputKey)
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Press the displayed number or symbol key.</h1>
        <h2>{this.state.subject}</h2>
        <div>
          <p>The number of questions: {this.maxSubject}</p>
          <p>The number of correct answers: {this.state.correctCount}</p>
          <button onClick={() => this.props.handleScreen("title")}>Return to title</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Game;
```

- Currently coded Class Component

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const MAX_SUBJECT = 5

const KEY_LIST = [
  "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", "-", "^", "\\",
  "@", "[",
  ";", ":", "]",
  ",", ".", "/",

  "!", "\"", "#", "$", "%", "&", "'", "(", ")", "=", "~", "|",
  "`", "{",
  "+", "*", "}",
  "<", ">", "?", "_"
];


function getRandomSubject() {
    const rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * KEY_LIST.length);
    return KEY_LIST[rnd];
}

function Game (props) {
    const [subject, setSubject] = useState(getRandomSubject)
    const [correctCount, setCorrectCount] = useState(0)
    const [incorrectCount, setIncorrectCount] = useState(0)
    const [elapsedTimeMs] = useState(() => Date.now())

    function onGameCompleted(){
        props.sendResult(correctCount, incorrectCount, elapsedTimeMs);
        props.handleScreen("result");
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        function readInputKey ({ key }) {
            if(key === subject) {
                setCorrectCount(correctCount + 1)
            } else {
                setIncorrectCount(incorrectCount + 1)
            }
        }
        window.addEventListener("keypress", readInputKey);
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener("keypress", readInputKey);
        }
    })

    useEffect(() => {
        if(correctCount < MAX_SUBJECT) {
            setSubject(getRandomSubject());
        } else {
            onGameCompleted({
                correctCount,
                incorrectCount,
                elapsedTimeMs: Date.now() - elapsedTimeMs,
            })
        }
    }, [correctCount, incorrectCount, elapsedTimeMs, onGameCompleted])

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Press the displayed number or symbol key.</h1>
            <h2>{subject}</h2>
            <div>
                <p>The number of questions: {MAX_SUBJECT}</p>
                <p>The number of correct answers: {correctCount}</p>
                <button onClick={() => props.handleScreen("title")}>Return to title</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Game;
```

Comment: Which component do you want to change it to the functional component?
`Game` Component?

Comment: Yes, but I can't do it well.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried and where is it not working correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code looks like it's working.
The only problems is that is a testing nightmare.
For a better correctness guarantee, I'd suggest you to use typescript, redux saga, or both.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

const MAX_SUBJECT = 10

const KEY_LIST = [
  "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", "-", "^", "\\",
  "@", "[",
  ";", ":", "]",
  ",", ".", "/",

  "!", "\"", "#", "$", "%", "&", "'", "(", ")", "=", "~", "|",
  "`", "{",
  "+", "*", "}",
  "<", ">", "?", "_"
];

function getRandomSubject() {
  const rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * KEY_LIST.length)
  return KEY_LIST[rnd]
}

function Game(props) {
  const [subject, setSubject] = useState(getRandomSubject)
  const [correctCount, setCorrectCount] = useState(0)
  const [incorrectCount, setIncorrectCount] = useState(0)
  const [elapsedTimeMs] = useState(() => Date.now())

  useEffect(() => {
    function readInputKey({ key }) {
      if (key === subject) {
        setCorrectCount(correctCount + 1)
        if (correctCount < MAX_SUBJECT) {
          setSubject(getRandomSubject())
        } else {
          props.sendResult(
            correctCount,
            incorrectCount,
            Date.now() - elapsedTimeMs,
          )
          props.handleScreen('result')
        }
      } else {
        setIncorrectCount(incorrectCount + 1)
      }
    }

    window.addEventListener('keypress', readInputKey)
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('keypress', readInputKey)
    }
  })

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Press the displayed number or symbol key.</h1>
      <h2>{subject}</h2>
      <div>
        <p>The number of questions: {MAX_SUBJECT}</p>
        <p>The number of correct answers: {correctCount}</p>
        <button onClick={() => props.handleScreen('title')}>
          Return to title
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Game
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply!
When I tried the code, I got the error "Line 72:52:'correctCount' is not defined no-undef".
Can "correctCount" be referenced from the "Game" component?

Comment: I broke the code while refactoring into a custom hook. Now it's fixed

Comment: Thank you very much!

However, I got the following error:
"Line 59:8:  React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'elapsedTimeMs', 'incorrectCount', and 'onGameCompleted'. Either include them or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps".

But if I include "incorrectCount" in the second argument, I don't think I get the desired result.
It's difficult for me to handle this error properly.

Comment: To get equivalent semantics, you can move the readInputKey function inside the useEffect hooks, and then add [elapsedTimeMs, incorrectCount, onGameCompleted] to its deps.

It's currently the same since the effect triggers on every render, but yes you could do that

Comment: I posted the modified code, is the code in the right place?
At this time, the following warning message was displayed.
"  Line 29:5:  The 'onGameCompleted' function makes the dependencies of useEffect Hook (at line 58) change on every render. Move it inside the useEffect callback. Alternatively, wrap the 'onGameCompleted' definition into its own useCallback() Hook  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps"

Comment: I've fixed it again, there are no linter warnings this time.
However, I've unintentionally proved my point: it's a non-trivial logic and a more testable/type-safe approach would prevent these subtle bugs and allow easier refactoring

Comment: Thank you! The warnings are gone and it worked as I expected!
If you don't mind, may I ask a question?
If a sequence of operations by a function is triggered by an event listener called in useEffect, does that mean that the entire sequence of functions had to be included in useEffect?
Also, does the typescript make it easier to take a testable/typesafe approach?